# Reindex Replaces Values with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill in missing times in a dataframe. when i reindex, the missing times are filled but my original values disappear and everything becomes a NaN. My code is as follows:

```
data = {'date':["2010-03-01 00:03:00","2010-03-01 00:05:00"], 'num':["1","2"]}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['date','num'])
pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_test.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df_test2 = df_test.reindex(pd.date_range(df_test.index[0], df_test.index[-1], freq='Min'))
```

df_test

```
                       num
date    
2010-03-01 00:03:00     1
2010-03-01 00:05:00     2
```

df_test2

```
                        num
2010-03-01 00:03:00     NaN
2010-03-01 00:04:00     NaN
2010-03-01 00:05:00     NaN
```

Comment: try: `df_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'])`

Answer (score 2):

Here is necessary assign back converted column to `datetimes`, because [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) not working inplace:

```
data = {'date':["2010-03-01 00:03:00","2010-03-01 00:05:00"], 'num':["1","2"]}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['date','num'])
df_test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_test.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

---

```
df_test2 = df_test.reindex(pd.date_range(df_test.index[0], df_test.index[-1], freq='Min')) 

print (df_test2)

2010-03-01 00:03:00    1
2010-03-01 00:04:00  NaN
2010-03-01 00:05:00    2
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df_test2 = df_test.asfreq('Min')
print (df_test2)
                     num
date                    
2010-03-01 00:03:00    1
2010-03-01 00:04:00  NaN
2010-03-01 00:05:00    2
```